# Prove this is an isosceles triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

In a $\triangle ABC$, $$\qquad \sin B\cdot\sin C=\cos^2\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)$$

Prove that this is an isosceles triangle.

Can anyone guide me to prove this? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note: in a triangle ABC, we have $A+B+C=\pi=180^o$

Given $$\sin B\sin C=\cos^2\frac{A}{2} \implies 2\sin B\sin C=2\cos^2\frac{A}{2} $$$$\implies \cos(B-C)-\cos(B+C)=2\cos^2\frac{A}{2} $$$$\implies \cos(B-C)-\cos(180^o-A)=2\cos^2\frac{A}{2} $$ $$\implies \cos(B-C)+\cos A=2\cos^2\frac{A}{2} $$$$\implies \cos(B-C)+2\cos^2\frac{A}{2}-1=2\cos^2\frac{A}{2}$$ $$\cos(B-C)=1 \implies B-C=0 \quad \text{or} \quad  B=C$$ Hence, the triangle ABC is an isosceles triangle

Comment: How B+C becomes $\pi-A$?

Comment: note in a triangle ABC, $A+B+C=\pi=180^o$